# Web socket authentication, is using a query parameter safe enough?

Tags: javascript, websocket

We're developing a web application that will fetch some data over a websocket. We serve it from CloudFront over SSL, the back-end is on AWS. We authenticate the users with Cognito for signing in with the application, and we would like to use the Cognito token to set up authentication for the websocket as well. Also, we want the token to be part of the first connection attempt, so that we don't open a connection to anyone, and then wait for some magic message containing auth, that could probably lead to DDoS attacks.

The first thought was to add the token to an authorization header, but the websocket standard doesn't support adding headers.

Second, we thought about adding an X-Authorization cookie with the token, that way the cookie would be sent as part of the request to open a socket. This failed (probably) because in development, the cookie domain is set to "localhost", and will not be sent to the websocket url of aa.bb.com.

Our next move is to append the token to the URL as a query parameter, and it seems to be working.

Now, my question is, is this safe enough, or should we consider something like a two-step approach, first get a sign-in token from another endpoint, then use that one as a query parameter when opening the websocket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your traffic is over `SSL` whatever solution works has the same security as the SSL no matter what method is used i.e. GET, POST...

Comment: That's what we were thinking, but when it comes to security, it doesn't hurt to ask around :D

Comment: I know this is an old question, but won't someone for example at the ISP have access to all the URLs sent through? 
I know https and wss are for secure data transfer, but what about the URLs?